# The oldest US space launch vehicles and stages still in use

Tags: rockets, history, stages

What are the oldest US space launch vehicles, or vehicle stages still in use?

I will definitely give you upvotes for answers suggesting any rocket or stage first launched in 1957-1965 and still in use today (actually launched after 2005).

If nothing is found in that period explain and provide younger candidates.

Comment: geoffc's one is better formulated.

Comment: I have to ask, is this a coincidence and just "one of those days", or does your question stem from some article that you both might have read? :)

Comment: We've discussed it in comments of a question: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/what-is-different-from-the-r-7-that-launched-sputnik-to-the-soyuz-launcher-used

Comment: Ah yes, that explains it! Anyway, please leave this question here as there's still some point in having duplicates - makes it easier to find answers via search. It's not a bad question, just unlucky that you both went for the same one at nearly the same time. ;) Cheers!